# Compile NDK code using gnu libstdc++

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I want to compile my NDK code using gnu libstdc++, any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a line to `Application.mk`

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

if you want to link it statically, and

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
```

if you want to use it as a shared library.

Here is the example of typical `Application.mk` (it should be placed into the same folder where your `Android.mk` is located):

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-7
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

More information on `Application.mk` can be found in your NDK docs: `docs/APPLICATION-MK.html`

Comment: @Sergey..Where can I find the reference libraries used by freeimage.h??

Comment: What do you mean? What ``reference libraries``?

Comment: Should I include any .h files or .c files so that freeimage.a work?

Comment: You should include only ``freeimage.h`` if you go with .a

Comment: @SergeyK...please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666200/ndk-error-on-doing-ndk-build

Comment: I get the same error as if the Application.mk wasn't there :(

Comment: Perhaps it isn't as though Application.mk isn't there since it seems to #include <vector> ok but it is like c++11 is not working. I have std::vector<int> ints = {1,2,3}; and i get the error message: In C++98 'ints' must be initialised by constructor not {}

Comment: Oh ive got it, needed to add APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu++11. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line to your Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

(or `gnustl_shared` if you don't want to link statically against it).

Comment: And read docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html file from Android NDK for more information about this.

Comment: I dont have an Application.mk now...I just have Android.mk..Can any one tell me what should be the format of Application.mk,preferably with an example? Thanks in advance

Comment: There should be an APPLICATION-MK.html file in the docs folder of your NDK installation.

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko..please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666200/ndk-error-on-doing-ndk-build